# Limit Output to only two decimal places

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

Output:

number of water molecules in 1.0 gm of water is: 3.341842397336293e+22

Expected Output:

number of water molecules in 1.0 gm of water is: 3.342e+22

Tried using round()

```
p = round(n,3)
n = 3.341842397336293e+22
p = round(n,3)
print(p)
```

output:

3.341842397336293e+22

and tried

```
  n = 3.341842397336293e+22
    print("%.3f"%n)
```

output :

33418423973362928713728.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.3e` as the [format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```py
n = 3.341842397336293e+22
print(f"... water is: {n:.3e}") # ... water is: 3.342e+22
```

> `'e'`: Scientific notation. For a given precision `p`, formats the number in scientific notation with the letter ‘e’ separating the coefficient from the exponent. The coefficient has one digit before and `p` digits after the decimal point, for a total of `p + 1` significant digits.